# How to write into a python tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a text widget in my gui but cannot figure out how to write to it on certain specified lines. Is it possible to make it always have some words in one place when the program is started and then to have other numbers associated with variables entered in other places.

```
txtReciept = Text(root)
txtReciept = Text(root, width=76, height=50)
txtReciept.pack()
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). On that note why are you creating the `Text` widget twice? Delete that first line.

Comment: Have you read through any documentation? Methods for inserting text into a text widget are well documented, and there are countless examples on the internet. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text widget cannot be written to sparsely. That is, if you want to write to row 10, you must have data on rows 1-9. Likewise, if you want to display something at a specific column, you must have data in all of the columns leading up to it.